# Pytyhon Tkinter Spin "focusout" validation

Tags: python, validation, tkinter, widget

I tried to validate my "spinbox" data on "focusout" event (for few days) and I'm completly lost...

I want to diferentiate 3 cases:

- Focus In / Focus Out (without put anything)
- Focus In and put something wrong
- Focus In and put something right

It's impossible to differentiate the firts case. Even using "S" or "s"...

```
import re
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from ttkthemes import ThemedTk



class Example(ttk.Frame):

    # CONSTRUCTOR
    def __init__(self, parent):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.time = DoubleVar(value = 1.0)

        vcmd = (self.register(self.onValidate),'%P','%S','%V')
        
        self.button = ttk.Button(root).pack(side="bottom", 
                       fill="both", expand=True)
        self.spin_time = ttk.Spinbox(root , from_= 1 , to = 99 , 
                       increment = 0.5 , wrap = True , width = 4 , 
                       textvariable = self.time , validate = 
                       "all" , validatecommand = vcmd)
    
        self.spin_time.pack(side="bottom", fill="both", 
                            expand=True)

    # VALIDATION METHOD
    def onValidate(self, P, S, V):
        # KEY VALIDATIONS
        # Correct validation (number, "." and all <=4)
        if V == "key" and (S[0].isdecimal() or S[0] == ".") and 
           len(P) <= 4:
            return True
        
        # FOCUSOUT VALIDATIONS
        elif V == "focusout":
            self.spin_time.select_clear()

            # Enter if you put something valid in the spinbox (I 
            #  don't know how to use "s" or "S" parameter)
              if self.spin_time.get() != "":

                # Enter if is a decimal
                if (re.fullmatch(r"\d*" , P)) or 
                   (re.fullmatch(r"\d+\.[0]" , P)) or 
                   (re.fullmatch(r"\d+\.[5]" , P)):
                    
                    # Enter if is it into range
                    if float(P) >= 1 and float(P) <= 99:
                        self.time.set(float(P))
                        return True
                    
                    # Wrong data
                    else:
                        self.time.set(1.0)
                        return False
                # Wrong data
                else:
                    self.time.set(1.0)
                    return False
            
            # Enter if you leave spin in blank
            else:
                self.time.set(1.0)
                return False
        
        # OTHER VALIDATIONS
        else:
            return False

# MAIN
if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = ThemedTk()
    Example(root).pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

Could you help me, please?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Please also include in the code how you're defining the spinbox and associating it with this validation function.

Comment: Ok, done. Sorry.

Comment: The code still isn't runnable. Apparently this code is in a class, and you haven't defined `self.callback` or shown how you define `self.time`. Please read [mcve].

Comment: Ok, done. Sorry again.

Comment: How are you creating a focusout event since you only have a single widget?

Comment: Ok, I added a button to be able to change within 2 widgets and I changed validation to "all".  My probleme now is the same: I need to manage the case: focusin/focusout without enter anything. I can't do it with a flag neither "S" or "s" parameter.

Comment: The focus events don't know anything about the data. They only know if the focus has changed. There is no focus-and-change or change-and-focus. It's up to you to track when the data changes. For example, you can save the current value before any changes and then check on focus out if the current value is different.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not explaining so good. My code manages when I no put anything. This is that I don't want. If I simply put the focus on the spinbox and leave the focus, my code manages that situation like I put some numbers in the spinbox. Ok, you could think obviously, If you manage the spinbox directy 'self.spin_time.get()!=""' this is normal, but I tried with 'S!=""' and the code manages similary ALWAYS the situation and I want to avoid a validation If the user don't input anything.